# Transformar array em XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Estou tentando transformar um array em um XML

Meu XML precisa ter a seguinte estrutura

```
<Products>
  <Product name="TR-501">
    <Descricao texto="55.180.198 / 46789771" />
    <Detalhes>
      <Variacao modelo="Palio" ano="2006" motor="1.0 FIRE 8V (FLEX)" />
    </Detalhes>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

para fazer a conversão estou utilizando a seguinte função em php

```
// function defination to convert array to xml
function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
    foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
        if( is_numeric($key) ){
            $key = 'item'.$key; //dealing with <0/>..<n/> issues
        }
        if( is_array($value) ) {
            $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
            array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        } else {
            $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
    }
}
```

e estou obtendo o seguinte retorno

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Products>
    <product>
        <name>TR-501</name>
        <description>55.180.198 / 46789771</description>
        <detalhes>
            <variacao>
                <item0>
                    <modelo>Palio</modelo>
                    <ano>2006</ano>
                    <motor>1.0 FIRE 8V (FLEX)</motor>
                </item0>
                <item1>
                    <modelo>Palio</modelo>
                    <ano>2006</ano>
                    <motor>1.0 FIRE 8V (FLEX)</motor>
                </item1>
                <item2>
                    <modelo>Palio</modelo>
                    <ano>2006</ano>
                    <motor>1.0 FIRE 8V (FLEX)</motor>
                </item2>
            </variacao>
        </detalhes>
    </product>
</Products>
```

Como eu posso fazer para que eu consiga obter varias linhas de  com os dados relativos dentro ao invés de `<item0> <item1> <item2>`? 
Obs: a maneira como os dados são exibidos dentro dos itens, seja por propriedade ou conteudo das tags é irrelevante, é relevante apenas que eu consiga obter varias linhas de `<variacao>` diferentes sem `<item0> <item1>`. Ex:

```
<Variacao modelo="Palio" ano="2006" motor="1.0 FIRE 8V (FLEX)" />
  <Variacao modelo="Palio" ano="2001/2004" motor="1.0 FIRE 8V (FLEX)" />
  <Variacao modelo="Palio" ano="2003/2006" motor="1.3 FIRE 8V" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é estares a acrescentar mudares as chaves do array associativo para "item" mais um número:

```
$key = 'item'.$key;
```

Além disso, não tem forma de distinguir os atributos dos elementos descendentes.

Deixo outra implementação para o que pretendes:

```
<?php

function array_to_xml(array $data) {
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    array_to_xml_aux($data, $document);
    $document->formatOutput = true;
    return $document;
}

function array_to_xml_aux(array $data, DOMNode $parent, $name = null)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if ($key[0] == '@') {
            $parent->setAttribute(
                substr($key, 1),
                $value
            );
            continue;
        }

        if (is_numeric($key)) {
            $key = $name;
        }

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $areAllInt = true;
            foreach(array_keys($value) as $k) {
                if (!is_int($k)) {
                    $areAllInt = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ($areAllInt) {
                array_to_xml_aux($value, $parent, $key);
            } else {
                $subnode = new DOMElement($key);
                $parent->appendChild($subnode);
                array_to_xml_aux($value, $subnode, $key);
            }

        } else {
            $xml_data->appendChild(new DOMElement($key, $value));
        }
    }
}
```

Atenção que para motivos de simplificação não coloquei validações e estou a assumir que as strings estão em formato ASCII. Usei a biblioteca DOM ao invés do SimpleXML (que estavas a usar).

Se fizer:

```
$document = array_to_xml(
array(
     'Products' => array(
            'Product' => array('@name' => 'TR-501'),
            'Descricao' => array('@text' => '55.180.198 / 46789771'),
            'Detalhes' => array(
                'Variacao' => array(
                    array(
                        '@modelo' => 'Palio',
                        '@ano' => '2006',
                        '@motor' => '1.0 FIRE 8V (FLEX)',
                    ),
                    array(
                        '@modelo' => 'Palio2',
                        '@ano' => '2007',
                        '@motor' => '1.0 FIRE 9V (FLEX)',
                    ),
                )
            ),
        )
    )
);
echo $document->saveXML();
```

a saída será:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Products>
  <Product name="TR-501"/>
  <Descricao text="55.180.198 / 46789771"/>
  <Detalhes>
    <Variacao modelo="Palio" ano="2006" motor="1.0 FIRE 8V (FLEX)"/>
    <Variacao modelo="Palio2" ano="2007" motor="1.0 FIRE 9V (FLEX)"/>
  </Detalhes>
</Products>
```

O código pode ser visto e testado em: https://3v4l.org/78Pjl
(se ninguém o alterar)

Volto a notar que estou a usar a biblioteca DOM:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Estavas a usar a biblioteca SimpleXML:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

O DOM é um padrão que até os browsers e Javascript usam e é mais rápido do que o SimpleXML (que usa DOM internamente).

Também é preciso diferenciar os atributos dos elementos descendentes. Eu fiz isso com o prefixo "@".

Para acrescentar vários elementos com o mesmo nome dentro de um mesmo elemento, basta usar um array sem chaves explícitas. Exemplo:

```
               [...]
               'Variacao' => array(
                    array(
                        '@modelo' => 'Palio',
                        '@ano' => '2006',
                        '@motor' => '1.0 FIRE 8V (FLEX)',
                    ),
                    array(
                        '@modelo' => 'Palio2',
                        '@ano' => '2007',
                        '@motor' => '1.0 FIRE 9V (FLEX)',
                    ),
                )
                [...]
```

Se queres um formato diferente, deve haver uma explicação de como queres.

Comment: Olá Pedro, testei utilizar sua implementação, porém o problema persiste o mesmo, não consigo gerar duas linhas de <Variacao> com valores diferentes

Comment: Me parece ter algo estranho neste else 
`} else {
            $xml_data->appendChild(new DOMElement($key, $value));`
        }

Comment: Fiz uma correcção e alterei a resposta para mostrar um exemplo com "duas linhas de <Variacao> com valores diferentes". O código pode ser testado em: https://3v4l.org/BquYA

Comment: Boa Pedro! Funcionou!